# SSH connection with .pub file

Tags: ssh

I am given with id_rsa.pub from client. And I was told to connect to it. I tried adding the key with `ssh-copy-id user@ec2-remoteserver.com`

But it gave the error. `Permission denied (publickey).`

Then I thought of trying to connect with

```
ssh -i /c/Users/kdash/Desktop/id_rsa.pub user@ec2-instance.com
```

It now says the error

`Load key "/c/Users/kdash/Desktop/id_rsa.pub": invalid format`

Can anyone please help me understand how shall I add the given .pub key file and access to the remote server.

Earlier I had connected to servers with .pem files as such:

```
ssh -i /c/Users/kdash/Desktop/server.pem user@ec2-instance.com
```

I am not clear how .pub file can be used.

Comment: You cannot connect to a server using the .pub file, this is only the public key part. The client may wanted you to add it to a server you own, so he could connect

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ferrybig. Client owns the server. And I asked him to give me access to reach dev instance on ec2. So he provided the .pub file and the syntax `ssh -i SSH/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@domain.com`. And told me that I can use the syntax to reach dev instance.

In past I have connected to ssh with .pem files from client. And that too without any .pub file. So I am unsure why he gave me .pub file this time and how to connect?

Comment: I think I should be sending the .pub key file to client.

Comment: Its usually the most secure if you generate a new keypair on your computer, then send your `.pub` file to the client, and then the client should append that file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, this way, the client can be sure that someone coming from that key is you, instead of someone who is sniffing data from the mail/whatever method of communication is used. See [Server admin sent me a private key to use. Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328555/43400)

Comment: Thanks Ferrybig. Now it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client should provide you the private key to connect to server.

I am sure client must have added the public key in their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Once client provide you the private-key file, then you can connect as

`ssh -i <private-key> user@ec2-instance.com`

See example [here](https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh), remote machine is adding public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and then user can connect to it using private key.

> So I guess, you need private key file to connect to remote ssh server.
>
> Remote machine should never add private key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I was unaware of this whole concept. But now I do. Thanks to you. I will get the private key from client. Or if he disagrees, I will send my public key and ask him to add it to his server.